# how to handle braces mark?

Tags: html, curly-braces

Here is my problem:

in css

```
table{
    position:absolute;
    top:-100px;
    left:90px;
    margin:300px;
    background-color:#000000;
    a:link {text-decoration:none;}
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
    a:hover {background-color:Green;}
    a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
}
```

`{` mark which is next to `table` is closed by `}` mark that the end of `a:link {text-decoration:none;}` and opening brace mark `{` which is right next to `a:link` and closing brace mark `}` at the bottom are becoming useless.

How can I connect that first and last `{` `}` marks with each other ? (not with that `a:link {text-decoration:none;}` this line's brace)

Comment: Are you sure you want to wrap those a in the table braces?

Comment: The above syntax requires a compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not correct CSS syntax. Correct would be:

```
table{
    position:absolute;
    top:-100px;
    left:90px;
    margin:300px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
table a:link {text-decoration:none;}
table a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
table a:hover {background-color:Green;}
table a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
```

If you want to nest CSS rules using the syntax in your question, you can use an alternate stylesheet language that compiles to CSS like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://www.sass-lang.com).